# Date grouping python

Tags: python, datetime, object

Can i borrow someone's brain for this issue. 
I have got data and their relevant timestamps. 
I am interested in grouping them by 5min frequency however i can only start the grouping on 00:00 format. I mean 13:23:27 (hours) would need to be group with 13:25:00 data and then it will be 13:30:00, 13:35:00 etc

Do you know how i can distinguish this rounding?
At the moment i am able to group by 5min but it starts from the first timestamp which could be 13:18:47 so the next one is  giving me is 13:24:00 which is wrong as per my definition i would like to see 13:20:00

Hope that make sense...

Comment: Sort of makes sense, but if you posted your code it would make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Rounding off your time to the nearest 300 seconds. you can use an inbuilt function of rounding off the integer. You can also try use this algorithm:

```
    function round(int timestamp){
        int N = timestamp;                  //The time in time stamp
        int RN;                 //The rounded off time stamp -- wch is our answer
        int n = 300;            //5 min interval in seconds
        int r = N%n;            //The remainder
        int x=N/n;              //the whole number we get after dividing

        if(r/n < 0.5){
            RN = x * n;
        }
        else{
            RN = (x * n)+5;
        }

        return RN;
    }
```

Hope it works, all the best

Comment: This is way more complicated than necessary, and nor is it python.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to seconds, divide by 300 and use the integer portion as your grouping.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` will help too.

Answer (score 0):

```
times = [<a list of datetimes>]
timegroups = [list(group) for (key, group) in
              itertools.groupby(times, lambda t:(t.hour, t.minute // 5))]
```

#### Things to note:

- Make sure you `import itertools`.
- `//` is floor division (even though SO's syntax highlighter thinks it's a comment)
- `itertools.groupby` will return an iterator that depends on the original iterator, with which you can loop over if needed. I converted it to a list so you can easily see what the results are.
- `groupby` will also expect a sorted list
- If you need more resolution in your grouping, just modify the tuple returned by the lambda

The key here is the floor division of the minutes by 5 -- this is what will achieve the grouping you're looking for; that single statement is all the logic you need.

#### Edit:

In order to do what the (currently) accepted question is doing, this is the change needed:

```
rounding_delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=150)
def key_func(val):
    t = val + rounding_delta
    return (t.hour, t.minute // 5)
timegroups = [list(group) for (key, group) in
              itertools.groupby(times, key_func)]
```

Comment: You cannot convert `groupby()` results to a list and expect the underlying per-group iterators to still work. Each iteration returns `key, group`, with `group` being an iterator yielding values from `times`, but if you go to the next group without consuming those, *you cannot get them at a later time*.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I wasn't really thinking. Fixed.